# Giving a file/directory the same modification date as another

Tags: bash, unix, unix-timestamp

How do I "copy" the modification date and time from one file/dir to another in Unix-based systems?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have some options:

- Use `touch -t STAMP -m file` if you want to change the time
- Use `cp --preserve=timestamps` if you're copying the files and want to preserve the time
- **Use `touch -r` to set the time to a "reference" file**

Comment: This tells me how to apply a stamp to a particular file, and copy a file and preserving timestamps. But it doesn't answer my original question about how to copy a timestamp from one preexisting file to another preexisting file...

Answer (score 15):

This will do exactly what you are asking:

```bash
touch -r ref path
```

The above changes `path`'s modification time to match `ref`'s modification time.

Answer (score 4):

For convenience later on, put the following lines in your .bashrc file:

```
cptimestamp() {
  if [ -z $2 ] ; then
    echo "usage: cptimestamp <sourcefile> <destfile>"
    exit
  fi
  touch -d @$(stat -c "%Y" "$1") "$2"
}
```

Execute "source ~/.bashrc" and you're ready to go.  If you prefer a script instead, remove the first and last lines -- then prepend "#!/bin/sh"

Answer (score 1):

You can get the timestamp of source file using `stat` in unix timestamp format and then propagate it to the destination file using `touch -d`

```
src_file=/foo/bar
dst_file=/bar/baz

touch -d @$(stat -c "%Y" "$src_file") "$dst_file"
```

NOTE: This would only work with `GNU coreutils` which support the unix timestamp using the prefix `@` with `touch`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`touch`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/touch/); it contains several optional flags that allow you to set such attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cp, use the -p option to preserve mod times.
    cp -p