# ext4 copy file to directory without changing directory timestamp

Tags: linux, timestamp, cp

I'd like to copy a file to a directory without changing the modification timestamp of the directory on an ext4 filesytem. Well, many files and many directories in a script.

I've looked at rsync and cp options.

So to frame the question, how do I copy a file on an ext4 filesystem and preserve the timestamp on the destination directory?

There are many ways to copy files and preserve their attributes but they modify the parent directory timestamp. What's needed is the two step process of recording that timestamp and applying it after the copy. That was not addressed in the question referenced. [Giving a file/directory the same modification date as another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181024)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Man, you made no effort... Possible duplicate of [Unix Shell scripting for copying files and creating directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/494880/608639), [Giving a file/directory the same modification date as another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15181024/608639), [How to copy a file in unix without altering its last modified time?](https://superuser.com/q/114195/173513), [Force file creation time for all files transferred to a directory](https://askubuntu.com/q/718235), [How do I copy a file and retain the *original date*?](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=186472), etc.

Comment: None of those really made the crucial point that the original dir timestamp needs to be saved temporarily then reapplied once the copy is done. Thanks for taking the time to point them out though. But yes, sorry, wrong forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to save and restore the timestamp:

```
# Save current modification time
timestamp=$(stat -c @%Y mydir)

[.. copy/sync files ..]

# Restore that timestamp
touch -d "$timestamp" mydir
```

Comment: Thanks. It's great to have someone read a question before pointing me to a man page I've already read. I thought it might be something like that, just asking for a function :)

Comment: There are three timestamps: atime, mtime and ctime. Which one is `stat`'s option `Y` referring to? When using `touch -d` which of the three (or all) timestamps is it setting?

Answer (score 0):

See this [guid](https://www.shellhacks.com/fake-file-access-modify-change-timestamps-linux/). If you want to preserve original timestamp use

`$ touch -r <original_file> <new_file>`.

This copy the attributes from another file. If you need to change specific attributes use following.

For **Access time**

```
$ touch -a --date="1988-02-15" file.txt
```

For **Modify time**:

```
$ touch -m --date="2020-01-20" file.txt
```

To see stat of a file or folder, Use `stat <file>`

Answer (score 0):

`$ cp --preserve=timestamps oldfile newfile` 
or

`$ cp -p oldfile newfile` would do that. **Man** pages clearly state that.

Comment: This preserves the timestamp of the file, but not of the destination directory which is what OP asks about.